# How do I get my web component to scroll all the way to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component

I am creating a site using web components and polymer.

I am building a responsive layout, and most of my components are meant to live within the bounds of their parent.  For example, my main page is a fixed menu on top that stays there and any content on the page scrolls below it.

This almost works, but I cannot seem to get child components to pick up the correct size of their parent, and an artifact of this is that I cannot scroll a child component all of the way to the bottom of its content.

There are lots of answers out there involving knowing what the size of the fixed menu is, and compensating with a margin on the child, but the whole idea of web components is to build them independent of where they are attached to your app.

Any ideas on how I can get the "lorem ipsum" text in this example to scroll to the bottom with out a hack to hard code its location?  I need this to work whether it's the top level of the app or embedded 8 levels down.  What's the Right Answer?

The full plunker demonstrating the problem is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OlOeCP?p=preview

Here's the index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="top-menu.html">

  <style>
    html {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    body,
    html {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <top-menu></top-menu>
</body>

</html>
```

The top-menu component:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="lorem-ipsum.html">

<dom-module id="top-menu">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: pink;
      }

      .container {
        display: block;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .header {}

      .content {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        /*min-height: 0;*/
        background-color: orange;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <paper-toolbar>
          <div class="title">Test</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <lorem-ipsum></lorem-ipsum>
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'top-menu',
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And the sub-component, which just displays enough text to force scrolling:

```
<link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="lorem-ipsum">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .lorem {
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="lorem">
      <h4>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</h4> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

      <h4>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h4> "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
      quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
      modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
      qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

      <h4>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h4> "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
      of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
      exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"

      <h4>Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h4> "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
      assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus,
      ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."

      <h4>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h4> "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue;
      and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice
      is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently
      occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse
      pains."

      <h4>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</h4> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

      <h4>Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h4> "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
      quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
      modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
      qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

      <h4>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h4> "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
      of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who
      loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
      exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"

      <h4>Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h4> "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas
      assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus,
      ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."

      <h4>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h4> "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue;
      and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice
      is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently
      occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse
      pains."

      <h4>WHERE IS THIS LINE?</h4>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'lorem-ipsum',

      properties: {
        title: {
          type: String
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: This looks like height of content is shorter by the height of the navigation element. in this case i think You can use [ScrollMagic ](http://scrollmagic.io/) to pinning navbar. [Here](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html) is example pining. Set `duration` ah height of content when doc is ready.

Comment: I'll take a look at scrollmagic, but I'd like to know why this is happening and fix the root cause.  It seems like it's either something I'm doing in the hosting document, something I'm doing in the component, or both.

Comment: Also, the key here is that the leaf component here (<lorem-ipsum>) should pick up it's width and height from whatever parent it is attached to.  I'm not looking for a way to solve just the problem in the example.

How should a web component be configured so it can scroll within its parent the way it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to get this to work.  My solution is based on this post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2015/02/20/filling-the-remaining-height-of-a-container-while-handling-overflow-in-css-ie8-firefox-chrome-safari/

Which uses `display:table` to control heights.  I also found I had some missing `height:100%` annotations that were needed to propagate the height of the parent down to the children.

The trick includes a second div layer in the child that is a table-cell.  My top-menu component's template now looks like:

```
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .container {
        display: table;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .header {
        display: table-row;
      }
      .content {
        display: table-row;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .content-inner-wrapper {
        display: table-cell;
        height: 100%;
      }

    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <paper-toolbar>
          <div class="title">Test</div>
        </paper-toolbar>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="content-inner-wrapper">
            <lorem-ipsum></lorem-ipsum>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </template>
```

Here's a plunker of what I ended up with.  I'm sure it could be cleaner but it got me unblocked, and very slightly better-educated about the way dimensions are passed down.

http://plnkr.co/edit/J71E3G?p=preview

Comment: This solution ended up not working cross-browser.  Safari doesn't behave the same way as chrome for this example.  The ultimate solution was for me to fully understand how heights are inherited from parent to child in html, and also to use flexbox to control how tall each div is.